# USOBT & USOBT_C

Tags: authorization, sap-basis

What different USOBT from USOBT_C in SAP?

Answer (score 2):

USOBT contains the default values for the authorization check indicator and default values that can be maintained in su24 (what is there initially, and what will be there if you click the "sap defaults" button).  USOBT_C contains the current values in your system for the authorization check indicator, if you never changed any values, USOBT and USOBT_C will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, USOBT is for SAP only (table type W, system table), while USOBT_C is for customers (table type C, customizing table). You're not supposed to touch USOBT.

More info on security tables [here](http://www.saplib.com/list-of-sap-r3-security-table/)

Comment: I would think so (but then, 'im not a security expert). In our system, there is only 7 line on more then 200000 that have been modified (the same 7 whose modifier are not SAP and DDIC)